# Dynamic tool tips for Tab control

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a tab control with ShowToolTips = true.
 It works fine for static tool tips that I assigned to the tabs using ToolTipText property.
 Now I need to make the tool tips dynamic, i.e. change the tip's text before showing it, depending on the tab contents. So, I'd like to use something like MouseHover event to check which tab I am in and change the corresponding ToolTipText. Unfortunately, TabControl.MouseHover event does not tell me which tab the mouse hovers on.

Is there any other event/property I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

got the answer from Microsoft C# forum:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b9cb025-1f6f-468c-8402-29e1c9f8e1ab/dynamic-tool-tips-for-tab-control?forum=csharpgeneral